# Calculating the scrabble score of a word

Tags: javascript

```
letter = prompt("Enter a word please");
letter = letter.toUpperCase();

// define letters and respective scores
alphabet = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M', 'N','O','P','Q',
'R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
alphabetScore = [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10]

// start sum
sum=0

for (i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++)
{
switch(letter) 
        {
        case (alphabet[i]): sum+=alphabetScore[i]; break;
        default: sum=sum+0;
        }
}   
alert (sum);
```

I'm trying to build a program that calculates the Scrabble score of a word. But each time I type in a word - it returns 0. Why is this happening? Sorry for the continuous JS posts - I'm new to the language and have been take extra practical assignments to boost my knowledge of the language. In this case I've been experimenting with the switch statement within a for loop.

Comment: You're doing `sum = sum + 0;`, I don't know Javascript so I don't know what `default:`means but I don't see any other incrementation of sum.

Comment: I would like for JS to loop through a given word and depending on the alphabet it should add the number to the total to produce the score. For example: ABB should give a score of 7!

Comment: A `switch` statement with only one `case` and a `default` is exactly the same as an `if`/`else` - I understand that you're experimenting, but this is a really terrible pattern to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modeling the relationship between a letter and its Scrabble point value as an associative array rather than as two parallel arrays:

```
var word = prompt("Enter a word please");
word = word.toUpperCase();

scores = { 'A' : 1, 'B' : 3, 'C' : 3, /* ... */ 'Z' : 10 };

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; ++i) {
    sum += scores[word.charAt(i)] || 0;
}

alert(sum);
```

Comment: There is no associative array in Javascript. That thing you are describing is called an Object :)

Comment: You are probably aware that calulating the actual scrablle score, requires taking into consideration two other things: Board special tiles (double word / double letter, etc..) and calculating additional score for created cross-words

Comment: [I am indeed](http://cross-tables.com/results.php?p=436). Didn't look as though the OP was worried about that.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the appropriate way of using switch.

`switch` is commonly used to replace several consequential `if ... else if ... else if ... else`. It's as simple as that. In your case you just need a single `if` statement inside the loop. And you actually need a double loop.

```
for each letter in the word
  for each letter in the alphabet
    if they match
      increment score
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid looping over the entire alphabet for each letter in the word by defining the scores in the form of an object (a.k.a. associative array).  Also, your "letter" variable is actually the whole word, so you'd need to loop through the letters individually.  The following combines these two ideas:

```
var word = prompt("Enter a word please");
word = word.toUpperCase();

var alphabet = {
    A: 1,
    B: 3,
    C: 3,
    D: 2,
    E: 1,
    F: 4,
    G: 2,
    H: 4,
    I: 1,
    J: 8,
    K: 5,
    L: 1,
    M: 3,
    N: 1,
    O: 1,
    P: 3,
    Q: 10,
    R: 1,
    S: 1,
    T: 1,
    U: 1,
    V: 4,
    W: 4,
    X: 8,
    Y: 4,
    Z: 10
}

var letter, i, sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    letter = word[i];
    sum += alphabet[letter];
}
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a closer look at the line

```
switch(letter)
```

Yes?

Comment: or, better, `for (i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++)`

Comment: Have I got something mixed around?

Answer (score 1):

You're treating the entire word like it's a single letter, and trying to find where in the alphabet it is. Since it's not in the alphabet at all, you get zero. Instead, you need to loop over the letters of the word.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum = 0;
for(var i=0,l=letter.length;i<l;i++)
    sum += alphabetScore[alphabet.indexOf(letter[i])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let word = prompt("Enter a word please");

const scrabble = {
  a: 1, b: 3, c:3, d: 2, e: 1, f: 4, g: 2, h:4, i:1, j: 8,
  k: 5, l: 1, m: 3, n: 1, o: 1, p: 3, q: 10, r: 1, s: 1, t: 1,
  u: 1, v: 4, w: 4, x: 8, y: 4, z: 10
};

const sum = [...word].reduce((accu, letter) => { return accu + scrabble[letter.toLowerCase()]; }, 0);

alert(sum);
```